# Java distributed list or queue for online production algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, distributed, priority-queue, production-environment

I currently involved in a project to move our search algorithm which is based on dijkstra/a-star algorithm to a production system. Basically, the algorithm receives a request and starts a search until the optimal solutions is found, which usually takes a few seconds. The problem is that the prototype version of our algorithm relies on the JDK **priority queue** (which is basically a binary heap) which consumes a high amount of memory during the search. So one of the big problems is how to handle the scalability of the system if we want to put the algorithm in a production system, handling multiple requests concurrently. We are trying to figure out what's the best option to do that, and the ideas that are flying through our minds are:

- The most trivial approach is to create a new instance of the algorithm each time a request is received, but it does not look like an efficient way to solve the problem (we would require a high amounts of ram for each instance).
- Use some kind of persistent and efficient store/database to move part of the elements of the queue to there when the size of the queue is too big. This can alleviate the memory problems but new problems arise, like keeping the order between elements in the in-memory queue and the elements in the store.
- Delegate the task of handling the queue to a big framework, like Hazelcast. Each instance of the algorithm can use a [distributed queue with hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/3.0/manual/single_html/#Queue). The problem is that Hazelcast does not have any kind of sorted queues, so we have to explicitly handle the order of the queue from outside the queue, which is a big performance issue.
- We are also considering the idea of using ActiveMQ, although the framework is not designed for this sort of problems. [The priority queue of ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-support-priority-queues.html) manages only 9 different priorities, which is not enough for our problem as we sort the elements in the queue based in a float-value (infinity priorities).

We are completely lost in this architecture design problem. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Keep the actual data in database and maintain a Priority queue of hashed index of data + their corresponding priorities. That should not take up much space. Also, try implementing Priority Queue using Fibonacci heap instead of binary heap... Fibonacci is faster for larger data set.

Comment: You could use ZooKeeper or GridGain for distributed priority queues.

Comment: Hazelcast or Redis